# Count number of character occurrences in an array

Tags: c, arrays, loops

Very simple but I'm having trouble. I have a random sequence of letters in an array:

```
char box[] = "rbpbymgoybrppogrgxombpgpbpbooyogrrm";
```

I need to count how many times a certain letter appears (e.g. letter 'r').

Here is my program so far:

```
main() {
    int count = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(box); i++) {
        if(box[i] == '\r') count++;
    }

    printf("Red: %d", count);
}
```

Now I already have a hunch that using '\r' to try and recognize the character is what's not working. Is there another way to represent the characters and check them in the array? Do I use their ASCII equivalents?

Comment: `sizeof(box)` does not what you expect it to do. Use `strlen(box)` to get the length of the **string** which is stored in the array, not the total number of entries in the **array**. If you do not see the difference, please read about C strings and how they are related to `char` arrays (and `char *`).

Comment: this code will not compile, to start with, because main() ALWAYS returns an 'int'. and because the call to printf() requires the statement: `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: haven't touched upon #include <string.h> yet in class but after reading about it the strlen function sounds like a better fit.

Comment: also I did include #include <stdio.h> I just didn't mention that

Comment: `'\r'` is the carriage return character. `'r'` is the letter r.

Answer (score 2):

`'\r'` would mean a [Carriage Return](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwa1sfwk.aspx). Simply use `'r'`:

```
if(box[i] == 'r')
```

Comment: I see...have not touched upon that term yet...I usually use the backslash to recognize integers in my array but I didn't realize it's not the same way for characters.

Comment: Why would you use backslash to recognize integers in your array?

Comment: I'm not sure...I just assumed that's how it worked haha. So I'm guessing it works the same way for integers? I could just use '34' rather than '\34'?

Comment: There is confusion here: `'\34'` is a single character, namely the control character with ASCII value 28 (34 in octal) also known as FS (field separator) or control-underscore.  `'34'` is accepted by the compiler for historical reasons, but does not have defined semantics.  `'3'` is the character three and `'4'` the character four.

Answer (score 0):

the following code will give a count of every letter type in the input string

it should be easy to selectively only print the letter of interest in the second 'for' loop

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_CHAR_TYPES (256)

static char box[] = "rbpbymgoybrppogrgxombpgpbpbooyogrrm";

static unsigned int charCounts[ MAX_CHAR_TYPES ]= {0};

int main( void )
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < (sizeof(box)-1); i++)
    {
        charCounts[ (int)box[i] ]++;
    }

    for(int i=0; i < MAX_CHAR_TYPES; i++)
    {
        if( 0 < charCounts[i] )
        {
            printf("There were %d of the %c character\n", charCounts[i], (unsigned int)i);
        }
    }
    return 0;
} // end function: main
```

Comment: `charCounts[(unsigned char)box[i]]++;` would be more prudent in case the string has chars with negative value. And `UCHAR_MAX+1` should be used rather than `256`.

Answer (score 0):

In R Programming Language, this is what we get

```
>arr="aaaaafdgshghsghgshfsgfsaaadahsgdhsgdhaaaggghahgahgahghaghhhha"
>arr
#[1] "aaaaafdgshghsghgshfsgfsaaadahsgdhsgdhaaaggghahgahgahghaghhhha"
> aa=strsplit(arr,"")
> aa
#[[1]]
# [1] "a" "a" "a" "a" "a" "f" "d" "g" "s" "h" "g" "h" "s" "g" "h" "g" "s" "h" "f" "s" "g" "f" "s" "a" "a" "a" "d" "a" "h" "s"
#[31] "g" "d" "h" "s" "g" "d" "h" "a" "a" "a" "g" "g" "g" "h" "a" "h" "g" "a" "h" "g" "a" "h" "g" "h" "a" "g" "h" "h" "h" "h"
#[61] "a"
>table(aa[[1]])
#  a  d  f  g  h  s 
#  17  4  3 14 16  7
```